# How to install python package on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

I would like to install some python packages on Ubuntu 10.04.

I have problem with openssl version and there is no way to upgrade it on this Ubuntu. I have also tried downloading modules manually and running `python3 setup.py install` but it says that I don't have setuptools, which is also impossible to install on this Ubuntu.

Is there any alternative to pythonhosted.org that allows older openssl versions and how to set it up

Comment: Maybe you can try creating virtual environment and then install packages inside?

Comment: I have problem accessing pythonhosted.org even from browser. It says Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).
(Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Comment: 10.04 is old.  I was running it 4 years ago to support a legacy system and I had troouble with new packages then.  You can install a lot of things from source code if you really need to.  I would suggest using a newer version however

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend you to Install a newer version of ubuntu that is supported.
   1.1 Install all dependencies and install python via Terminal.

   `apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt -f install -y && apt install python3`

(This will most likely to be the solution)

2. This will execute it if you want to run a python file.

   `./package-name.py`

optionally use `make install` newer versions work well with this command too in the directory of the downloaded module.

3. For installing pythonmoduels

   `pip (or pip3) --user install modulename`

(pip or pip3 depends on which python you have installed.)

Comment: I can't upgrade Ubuntu unfortunately and because of those openssl version issues I can't even install pip